# Best SEO practices for mobile URLs: 301, rel=canonical, or something else?

Tags: url-rewriting, canonical-url, seo

I am developing a site with a mobile version and am trying to figure the appropriate way to manage the URLs for search engines. So far I've considered:

1. Having a separate mobile site (m.example.com) with
           rel="canonical" links to the regular
           site.
2. Putting both the mobile
           site and full site on one URL (example.com), and
           doing user agent sniffing.
3. Another
           opinion:

> Spencer: "If you have a mobile site at
>   a separate location or URL, you should
>   301 redirect each and every mobile
>   page to its corresponding page on your
>   main website. Employ user agent
>   detection so that the mobile optimized
>   version is served up if someone's
>   coming in from a hand-held.
>   - http://developer.practicalecommerce.com/articles/1722-Mobile-site-Development-Best-Practices-for-SEO-Usability

Both 2 and 3 make it hard for a user who wants to switch to the full site or mobile site manually, but I'm not sure 1 is the best alternative.

What's the best way to write URLs for a mobile site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know this question is old, but Google now provides better guidelines on how to develop website for Desktop and Smart Phones.

https://developers.google.com/webmasters/smartphone-sites/details

Comment: I'm wondering why google doesn't follow its own advice. They've always done UA sniffing.

Answer (score 2):

This [recent blog post from Google](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/) might be helpful

Comment: Hey, that's a great resource, but I read through it and don't feel that it answers the question.

Comment: The comments didn't answer it last I checked, but people are asking the right questions so hopefully there'll be an answer there soon: http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Webmasters/thread?tid=64f43a49a3ac2e27

Comment: That links to the root level of the Google Webmaster Central blog. Were you trying to link to http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2011/02/making-websites-mobile-friendly.html?

Answer (score 1):

This is an even older post now, but I recently implemented a mobile-specific sub-domain based on [this advice from Google](https://developers.google.com/search/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls).

> Google does not favor any particular URL format as long as they are all accessible for all Googlebot user-agents.

The important thing is that you signal to Google the relationship between the two sites so you don't get penalised for duplicate content. This means using  tag with rel="canonical" and rel="alternate" elements and redirecting visitors based on user-agent strings.